# dotnet build freez with .net sdk 2.1 on mac catalina

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I have an asp.net core 2.1 application, while using the dotnet build command on the project the msbuild hangs infinite

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

Build process

```
macbook@macbooks-MacBook-Air LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore % dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 92.43 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared.csproj.
  Restore completed in 92.61 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj.
  Restore completed in 92.63 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj.
  LegalRegTech.Core.Shared -> /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared.dll
MasterData/AuthorityProvision.cs(6,7): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'LegalRegTech.CustomData' appeared previously in this namespace [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Authorization/Users/UserEmailer.cs(331,50): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Authorization/Users/UserEmailer.cs(345,50): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Authorization/Users/UserEmailer.cs(1016,35): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Authorization/Users/UserEmailer.cs(1228,30): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Net/Emailing/LegalRegTechNullEmailSender.cs(40,27): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Net/Emailing/LegalRegTechNullEmailSender.cs(45,27): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Net/Emailing/LegalRegTechNullEmailSender.cs(50,27): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Net/Emailing/LegalRegTechNullEmailSender.cs(55,33): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Net/Emailing/LegalRegTechNullEmailSender.cs(61,27): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Net/Emailing/LegalRegTechNullEmailSender.cs(66,33): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Net/Emailing/EmailTemplateProvider.cs(50,13): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
Net/Emailing/LegalRegTechNullEmailSender.cs(71,37): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
MultiTenancy/Payments/Stripe/StripeGatewayManager.cs(298,34): warning CS0168: The variable 'inex' is declared but never used [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
MultiTenancy/Payments/Stripe/StripeGatewayManager.cs(291,30): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
MultiTenancy/Payments/Chargebee/ChargebeeGatewayManager.cs(399,30): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
RequirementBasedAssessments/Activities/RequirementAssessmentResponseActivityManager.cs(21,76): warning CS0169: The field 'RequirementAssessmentResponseActivityManager._assessmentDomainProvisionIssueRepository' is never used [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
RequirementBasedAssessments/Activities/RequirementAssessmentResponseActivityManager.cs(22,75): warning CS0169: The field 'RequirementAssessmentResponseActivityManager._assessmentDomainProvisionRiskRepository' is never used [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
  LegalRegTech.Core -> /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/LegalRegTech.Core.dll
```

Update after removing the asyn warning calls

```
macbook@macbooks-MacBook-Air LegalRegTech.Web.Core % dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Application/LegalRegTech.Application.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PDFsharp-MigraDoc-gdi 1.50.5147' was restored using '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Web.Core/LegalRegTech.Web.Core.csproj]
  Restore completed in 93.39 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared.csproj.
  Restore completed in 96.2 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Application/LegalRegTech.Application.csproj.
  Restore completed in 4.72 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared.csproj.
  Restore completed in 3.48 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.AzureCosmosDB/LegalRegTech.AzureCosmosDB/LegalRegTech.GraphDBConnector.csproj.
  Restore completed in 6.85 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj.
  Restore completed in 4.01 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj.
/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Web.Core/LegalRegTech.Web.Core.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PDFsharp-MigraDoc-gdi 1.50.5147' was restored using '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
  Restore completed in 5.75 ms for /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Web.Core/LegalRegTech.Web.Core.csproj.
/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Web.Core/LegalRegTech.Web.Core.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PDFsharp-MigraDoc-gdi 1.50.5147' was restored using '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Application/LegalRegTech.Application.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PDFsharp-MigraDoc-gdi 1.50.5147' was restored using '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
  LegalRegTech.Core.Shared -> /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared.dll
  LegalRegTech.GraphDBConnector -> /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.AzureCosmosDB/LegalRegTech.AzureCosmosDB/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/LegalRegTech.GraphDBConnector.dll
MasterData/Dtos/AuthorityControlDtos/DeleteProvisionInputDto.cs(11,20): warning CS0108: 'BulkDeleteProvisionsInputDto.AuthorityId' hides inherited member 'GetAllAuthorityByControlIdInput.AuthorityId'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared.csproj]
Authorization/Users/Dto/UserListDto.cs(64,21): warning CS0108: 'ApplicationUsersListDto.TenantId' hides inherited member 'UserListDto.TenantId'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared.csproj]
  LegalRegTech.Application.Shared -> /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/LegalRegTech.Application.Shared.dll
Authorization/Users/UserEmailer.cs(1225,30): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
  LegalRegTech.Core -> /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/LegalRegTech.Core.dll
```

Update after removing PDF

```
macbook@macbooks-MacBook-Air LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore % dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp2.1' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp2.1' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp2.1' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj]
  Restored /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared.csproj (in 1.78 sec).
  Restored /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj (in 1.81 sec).
  Restored /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj (in 1.84 sec).
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp2.1' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore/LegalRegTech.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp2.1' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
  LegalRegTech.Core.Shared -> /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/LegalRegTech.Core.Shared.dll
/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/Authorization/Users/UserEmailer.cs(1225,30): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used [/Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/LegalRegTech.Core.csproj]
  LegalRegTech.Core -> /Users/macbook/Projects/6clicks/src/LegalRegTech.Core/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/LegalRegTech.Core.dll
```

Comment: In your error message, there is a warning: warning CS1998: This async method lacks'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or'await Task.Run(… )'to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Remove all the async warnings

Comment: This is weird. Of course, you should just fix the code that is calling the warnings, but I cannot see why the build itself would hang. Was the first listing with the warnings complete?

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 is out of support. The oldest supported version is .NET Core 3.1 and now that .NET 6 is out, it will also go out of support in 1 year. The warnings complain you tried to use the *non-*.NET Core package `PDFsharp-MigraDoc-gdi 1.50.5147`. You *can't* use a .NET Framework library on a Mac

Comment: Looking at PDFSharp and MigraDoc I see they have no .NET Core versions. While you could get away with using .NET Framework libraries on Windows, on a Mac those libraries won't work at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated the question after the removal of the PDF

Comment: Fix the unsupported runtime too. This isn't just nagging. It means that even if you encountered a .NET Core problem, nobody's going to fix it. .NET Core works just fine on a Mac. I use it on a MacBook 2018 for the last 2 years, first with .NET Core 3, then .NET 5 and now .NET 6. I never had a hanged build. Beyond that, you don't provide any information. That project obviously never worked on a Mac since it used .NET Framework assemblies. Perhaps it contains other build steps that don't work. Perhaps it executes custom build events that freeze. We can't guess

Comment: You can try changing the verbosity level of the build to see what's going on when that apparent freeze occurs. Perhaps what you think as a freeze is a very long operation. At least you can see what step hanged. Try `detailed` or `diagnostic`. Check the Activity Monitor to see what's going on, which processes consume too much CPU. On the other hand, if a build step is trying to access the network and fails you may see the `dotnet` processes idling.

Comment: Try creating a *new* project in a different folder and build it. If the .NET Core installation is OK it won't freeze while building.

Comment: Finally, the problem may be caused by the outdated MacOS version. Catalina is two major versions behind. I never encountered problems with Catalina, but perhaps a custom build step does.